# Install Ubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu using Ubuntu iso image

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-netbook, pxe

I have a 6 year old laptop which through the years lost a CD drive and doesn't have any options to boot using a USB stick.

I somehow managed to install Ubuntu using pxe boot taking the Ubuntu distro from *us.archive.ubuntu.com*.

When I start my system, I see that there is no UI available and when I do a `uname` I get the following:

```
Linux machinename 2.6.31-23-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP
```

I want to install Ubuntu with Gnome on my machine, and I have an .iso image of Ubuntu 10.04.

Is there a way to install another Ubuntu version (fresh install on a partition would also work) from within Ubuntu using .iso image?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: Much better for me would be to install the Ubuntu netbook version or its better to install a simple Ubuntu desktop version?

Comment: Try and see what works best for you. Maybe [**this link**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053990/lubuntu-vs-xubuntu-for-development#1053990) can give you some tips. You can try Ubuntu community flavours with light desktop environment (instead of the netbook version, which is no longer developed.

Answer (score 2):

Since your old laptop has working network connectivity, it would probably be easier to install from the network:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Note that since the introduction of Unity, there is no longer a distinction between Ubuntu "netbook" and "desktop" editions.